# Orders of Modifying the Shape

Tags: opengl, transformation

I just started learning the Transformations in OpenGL, and I was confused about the steps of modifying a shape to different position, angles or sizes.

For example, we have a house in 2D scene as follow:
[image]

Let's say I want to transforms the scene in (a) into the scene in part (b) of the house, how should I decide whether should I scale it, translate it or rotate it first ? Is the outcome going to be different ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcome is definitely going to be different based on the order of transforms.

Here is some pseudocode that answers your question directly (assuming each function takes `x,y,z` as parameters):

```
translate(-6, 0, 0)
rotate(0, 0, 135)
scale(2, 1, 1)
```

Now let's look at why this order matters!

First, this is what we would have without any transforms:
[image: no transforms]

Next, let's see what happens when we rotate counter-clockwise by 45° and then translate along the positive X axis:

[image: rotate then translate]

Notice how the translation caused the square to move toward the top-right corner? This is because the rotation transform also modifies the local axes. Now positive X points to the top-right. If we rotated by 180° then +X would point towards the left instead of the right.

Now let's look at what happens when we perform the same transforms in the reverse order:

[image: translate then rotate]

This time the translation moved the square to the right as expected. After that the square was rotated.

Check out the [open.gl page on Transformations](https://open.gl/transformations) for more detail, especially around the math behind all of this.